# How to specify logback as project dependency?

Tags: sbt, logback

I am using sbt for an Akka project. I want to redirect the output of the logger. Therefore I'd like to use logback.

What do I have to add to `build.sbt` to manage the library dependency for logback?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3"
```